# Changing shortcut for vertex, egde, face

Tags: edit-mode

I habe Numpad enabled so 1,2,3 is set to change the view.

CTRL+TAB doesn't work anymore for switching between V,E,F mode?

What is the new shortcut to switch between V,E,F mode in Blender 3?

If not how to I set manually?

Comment: Ctrl Tab is made to switch between the interaction modes, not the selection modes, the shortcuts for those are 1, 2 and 3 of the standard numbers row of your keyboard. You can find and change the shortcuts in the Preferences panel > Keymap > click on Name and in the search field type mesh.select_mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> is to switch between the interaction modes, not the selection modes, the shortcuts for those are <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd> and <kbd>3</kbd> of the standard numbers row of your keyboard:

[image]

You can find and change the shortcuts in the *Preferences panel > Keymap >* click on *Name* and in the search field type *mesh.select_mode*:

[image]

Comment: But I use Numpad emulation so 1,2,3 are for the views. I will change it for something else. Thank you- I wish there would be native solution whern you enable Numpad, selection mode gets new shortcut.